# How to run `m (Either e a)` actions in an `ExceptT e m a` do block?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Trying out transformers for the first time (sort of), I'm trying to use the following function:

```
getEnvList :: Text -> IO (Either String [Text])
```

in the  do block of

```
type EitherIO a = ExceptT String IO a
script :: EitherIO ()
```

I think I should be able to do this:

```
entryKeys :: [Text] <- pure $ getEnvList active_cac_entries
```

However, I get this error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO (Either String [Text])’
                  with actual type ‘[Text]’
    • When checking that the pattern signature: [Text]
        fits the type of its context: IO (Either String [Text])
      In the pattern: entryKeys :: [Text]
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        entryKeys :: [Text] <- pure $ getEnvList active_cac_entries
   |
93 |   entryKeys :: [Text] <- pure $ getEnvList active_cac_entries
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right function for this situation is the `ExceptT` constructor:

```
ExceptT :: m (Either e a) -> ExceptT e m a

-- do ...
--    entry <- ExceptT $ getEnvList active_cac_entries
--    ...
```

Comment: Ah, somehow I thought `pure` would essentially be an alias for that, but I see now why that was faulty thinking: I suppose pure would have type: `a :: ->  ExceptT e m a`

Comment: @bbarker You can write `(pure :: ()) $ getEnv...` and learn from the error message what type GHCI expected `pure` to be instead of `()`.

Comment: @Redu shouldn’t `_` instead of `()` be a little friendlier since it’s a type hole?